# Getting last char of a string in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to get the last char of a string. For example:

```
?- last_char('abde', X).
X = 'e'

?- last_char('abdef', X).
X = 'f'
```

Could someone help me, please? I'm new to Prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with a little help from [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5, a really handy ISO builtin:

```
?- sub_atom(abdef, _, 1, 0, C).
C = f.
```

Comment: Great solution, I always learn new things about Prolog by reading your answers. I still posted my attempt though as it is a bit more readable :)

Comment: Great solution indeed! Thank you very much. I'm new to Prolog, I'm trying to learn all by myself. You really helped me, thanks!

Comment: @l4mpi: thanks. I glissed over much detail, specially about the atom vs. string differences...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `name` and `reverse` to convert the string to a list and back:

```
last_char(S, X) :-
    name(S, N),
    reverse(N, [F|_]),
    name(X, [F]).
```

Depending on your Prolog version you might have to import a `list` library for the `reverse` predicate, e.g. `:- use_module(library(lists)).` for SICStus.

Comment: I tryed to use name/2 and reverse/2 too, but it returns the code of the char, not the char itself.

Comment: @renatov That's why I used `name` a second time to convert it back. You can use either the string or the character list as an input argument and the other one as an output argument.