# Getting the first N chars of a String in prolog

Tags: prolog, substring

I am trying to get the first N chars of a string. From looking at the following question I understand I can use

```
> sub_atom(str, X, Y, W, Z).
```

[Getting last char of a string in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734799/getting-last-char-of-a-string-in-prolog)

The problem is that I can't find good documentation for this function, here is the formal doc:
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sub_atom/5

I will be happy for a link or explanation for how this func works. Also, I will be happy for help on the following example: 
How to get all chars that are before "/" in "prolog/a" that will work something like this:

> sub_atom(prolog/a, X , Y , W, Z). => prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the documentation is clear enough:

```
sub_atom(+Atom, ?Before, ?Len, ?After, ?Sub)
```

- **Atom** is the initial atom from which you ant to deduct the Subatom.
- **Before** is the position that the subatom starts, counting starts from 1.
- **Len** is the length of the Subatom
- **After** is the length of the the remaining subatom, e.g `sub_atom(abc, 1, 1, After, b).` gives `After = 1` (remaining is c which is of length 1)
- **Sub** is the Subatom acquired from the initial atom.

In your example the problem is that `prolog/r` is not an atom but a compound term because it contains `'/'`. Though `"prolog/r"` (in double quotes as a string) is an atom.

I suggest to use `atomic_list _concat/3` in order to achieve that

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L, '/', "prolog/r").
L = [prolog, r].
```